# mysql query to get all number with excluding two type if fields

Tags: mysql

There is mysql table with mdn,cir,pid,status 
i want to find all mdn which are not in x and Y cir using  PID as Z ..dont want to use sub query or multiple queries .

```
this is what i have tried but it is giving me wrong answer  :

select * from tbl where (cir not in ('X','Y') && PID not in ('Z')) ;
```

Comment: `select * from tbl 
where cir not in ('X','Y') AND PID <> 'Z'`

Comment: Add some sample records from your table to the post and specify which are the expected records ...

Comment: @juergend I don't think this is what he meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you, you want all, excluding the rows where `cir in('x','y')` + `pid = 'z'` **together**, not each one separately so:

```
select * from tbl
where NOT(cir in ('X','Y') AND PID ='Z') ;
```